# Virtually reconnecting keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, manjaro, backlight

My problem is as follows: I use a Steelseries Apex M800 keyboard, which means it has proprietary RGB software for the keyboard backlight (I chose my keyboard before I switched to Linux, so I am aware of the quality of this choice :( ). Now about 50% of the time the backlight doesn't work on boot and the only way to fix it is to manually pull out the USB plug and reconnect it again.

I am looking for a way to virtually accomplish the same thing so I wouldn't have to crawl under my desk every morning just so I could see my keys. I'm trying to find a sort of "hard reseating the USB cable" script. I tried several scripts I found across the web, including [this](https://github.com/netinvent/usb_resetter/blob/main/usb_reset.py), [this](https://github.com/mcarans/resetusb/blob/master/reset_usb.py) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line).

I'm pretty sure they are all trying to do very similar things and it doesn't seem to work.
Anybody got an idea what command and/or script I could still try out to completely disconnect and reconnect my keyboard, similar to pulling the plug out and putting it back in again?
I use Manjaro with a 5.15 kernel in case that is relevant.

Comment: Ha! Could you tell (from your bootlogs / initlogs) if I can compare with my *Razer keyboard ?* => Your device is first attached to the hid-generic driver, then, when modeprobe-ing some dedicated driver is trying to take the lead ?

Comment: And when the dedicated driver fails to take the lead, you must unplug/replug your keyboard in order for the plug&play device to be directly attached to the dedicated driver ? (Pure speculation.) For info (in order to in/con-firm) about what could look like your logs, see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727535/razer-keyboard-use-keyboard-as-mouse-under-x notes 2 and 3

Comment: Gonna be real with you: I'm by no means a newbie with Linux (I've dabbled in Gentoo and Arch several times already) but I have absolutely NO idea what the devil you do in that post. I feel like I am waaaaay on the left side of the Dunning Kruger graph rn lol. No idea how the Kernel communicates in what order over what method with the keyboard in detail or how I would go about checking that even. If you have some commands you want me to run to get you more info I am open for it though lol.

Comment: Fair enough. I did tried my best to make **you** wonder by pulling you out of your area of comfort and, rather than first thinking that **you** were possibly comfortably installed in a wrong perception of your problem, you prefer believing I'm rude. Let it be. BTW, All what I meant is that you get stuck (title of your question + the 3 links you post) with the idea that THE solution is to "virtually unplug/replug your device". What I wanted you to understand is that in a plug&play system you can **unbind** devices from their driver and **bind** them to other drivers.

Comment: Anyway, no hardfeeling and have luck into your area of comfort.

Comment: Great, now instead of trying to be the Mr. Miyagi of Linux, how about you just write it like that to begin with when I clearly showed I have absolutely 0 idea of what you are getting at instead of cussing around like an illiterate monkey? You did a terrible job at pretty much all of your explanation so far. You are clearly at a point where it is absolutely inconceivable for you that someone has less knowledge about the topic than you do. Next time if people are looking for help stop trying to be a Sensei and just help them fix the issue.

Comment: I already wrote "fair enough". If you keep insisting, I will wonder whether some individuals are, *ad vitam aeternam*, condemned to *"crawl under their desk every morning"*. In this hypothesis, I would tend to name… : Those incredibly unable to realize the difference between a *comment* and an *answer* :-P