# mouse on linux sometimes very slow: (II) event3: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost

Tags: linux, kernel, xorg

i have this problem on fedora and debian. when i move the mouse it sometimes becomes very very slow, like on glue. the error in my Xorg.0.log i see is:

```
[   444.142] (II) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   444.151] (II) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   444.161] (II) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   444.191] (II) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   444.250] (II) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[   444.250] (II) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 30s). Discarding future messages.
[   444.819] (EE) event3  - Razer Razer Viper 8KHz: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 23ms, your system is too slow
```

i have no problems on windows, so i am nearly 100% sure this is some linux problem. i also did not encounter problems with wayland with the mouse, but i want to use xfce and there is not yet a release for xfce and wayland (tested it with kde wayland).

anyone an idea how to fix that? i also tested it with the latest mainline kernel (6.6.2), same behaviour. my system shouldnt be too slow (7950x3d) to handle the mouse :)

Comment: Razer Viper ? Have you installed the OpenRazer driver ? Is the daemon running ?

Comment: i did not install any additional driver. so there is also no daemon running for that. why is that required? installed it now but wondering why is that required.

Comment: I have a couple of Razer devices and fact is that each of them exposes just too many sub-devices to the kernel and therefore events to X11 this sometimes confusing X11. The Opendriver helps associating the right sub-device to the right event. BTW, I do not run the daemon much more dedicated to gaming facilities. If installing Opendriver makes things work for you, I'll write a more detailed answer. Good Luck !

Comment: For the record of one of my troubles with Razer devices and the incredible number of sub-devices per device, you can read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727535/razer-keyboard-use-keyboard-as-mouse-under-x

Comment: /sub-device/s//interface

Comment: hm, until now i did not have any problems, looks really promising. i will work with my machine and report back tomorrow.

Comment: 4h without any problem. so it really seemed to fix that problem. if you want to answer that, i'll flag it as solution! thanks!!! this was driving me nuts :)