# mouse freeze - SYN_DROPPED event when using graphical applications

Tags: xorg, nvidia, mouse, i3, libinput

I first noticed the issue when using Davinci Resolve (video editor) : I get random mouse freezes logged by the X server as "SYN_DROPPED event"

```
$ tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[...]
[ 12781.613] (II) event14 - USB OPTICAL MOUSE : SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[ 12782.295] (II) event14 - USB OPTICAL MOUSE : SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[...]
```

I don't get anything in `dmesg`.

I have then tested a few things, I get the same freezes when doing [this browser benchmark](https://web.basemark.com) on step 4 (webGL 1.0.2) and step 5 (webGL 2.0) **but only when I move my mouse from one physical display to another**.
I get this when starting my browser (or video editor) with `prime-run` and without.

*edit :* i've tried to replicate while following `journalctl` and when i get

```
[   302.377] (II) event14 - USB OPTICAL MOUSE : SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.` in `var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

I also get

```
déc. 05 10:03:20 hostname rtkit-daemon[2092]: Warning: PolicyKit call failed: Failed to open file “/proc/5693/status”: No such file or directory
```

in `journalctl`

*Some info :*

```
$ neofetch
[...]
OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64
Kernel: 6.1.65-1-lts
WM: i3
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800HS with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 Max-Q 
GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir 
[...]
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 6.6.1-arch1-1-g14 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 17 Nov 2023 16:32:51 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
```

my screen setup :

```
xrandr --output eDP --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1-0.1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1-0 --off --output DP-1-1 --off
```

```
$ pacman -Q | grep nvidia
nvidia-dkms 545.29.06-1
nvidia-hook 1.3-1
nvidia-inst 23-10
nvidia-installer-common 23-7
nvidia-prime 1.0-4
nvidia-settings 545.29.06-1
nvidia-utils 545.29.06-1
opencl-nvidia 545.29.06-1
python-nvidia-ml-py 12.535.133-1
```

Do you have any idea or pointers (pun intended) to where I could look to debug this ?
Thx

*PS : I've seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762159/mouse-on-linux-sometimes-very-slow-ii-event3-syn-dropped-event-some-input), but i have a freeze, not a slow-down, and it's only when having specific workloads*